# Reading Java properties file with Compass (config.rb)

Tags: ruby, sass, velocity, compass-sass

Is it possible to read key-value java properties (images.properties) in config.rb using Compass?

We have the following properties in images.properties that store relative paths to our images and they need to be created as variables in config.rb to be passed into sass_options. Consequently, they'll be injected in SASS code so that the image references are available in .CSS (i.e. *background: url('...')*) after being compiled:

> **images.properties** content:

```
images.logo=/assets/images/CompanyLogo.png
images.welcome=/assets/images/Welcome.png
```

The technical requirement is to have a single source of image locations in order to be available in html and css. We use Velocity to read java properties and use them in html, but for CSS we need to use Compass to inject the image paths in CSS selectors (class/id).

Answer (score 0):

This in unfortunately not possible with current technologies.